# Why Java and C# does not allow the creation of objects on the stack?

Tags: java, c#, c++, computer-science

Why I can create an object on the stack in C++ but I can't do that with other programming languages such as Java or C#?

Comment: Because the designers of the language didn't give you a way to do it. (Actually, Java at least has no concept of where an object is allocated; objects just *exist*)

Comment: @immibis - Escape analysis could atleast in theory allocate objects on stack itself.

Comment: @TheLostMind I don't think the question is about JIT optimizations.

Comment: C++ doesn't use a concept of stack explicitly, but it rather defines different types of object lifetimes. So in this case, you mean *automatic storage*.

Comment: @immibis - Agreed. I am merely pointing out that there is *a possibility* of that happening during runtime :)

Comment: @juanchopanza - Your comment actually answers the OPs question.

Comment: In C++ data can be allocated statically, dynamically on the stack, or dynamically on the heap. There are three categories of static data: global data, global class data, and static data local to a function.

Comment: @TheLostMind I don't know enough about C# to provide a good answer. I was under the impression what it allows some form of automatic storage. Also, I'm not sure 100% what the deal is with, say, local ints in a static method Java.

Comment: @juanchopanza - Am not sure about C# as well.. But in Java, the JVM is stack based, we basically push and pop stack frames when a thread enters a method. So, it has a well defined structure and size.. The variables are defined only in 2 classes, stack allocations and heap allocations.  But the way C++ is designed is different. The execution method is different, Obviously each method call has its stack frame in C++ as well.. But the major difference is you don't see *fields* as two *distinct* groups..You don't set a well defined specification of *what a stack frame is*.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simplicity: In C++ you have to manage all this memory allocation stuff yourself. Where is the object allocated, when is it freed.

In Java and C# (actually .NET), this is far easier. Objects are allocated on the heap and get garbage collected when not needed anymore. This eliminates a whole range of problems (Memory leaks and accessing freed objects)

Comment: You hardly have to "manage" memory allocation yourself in C++, unless you really want to. And more often than not, you don't want to.

Comment: Yeah, it's funny that people say you have to manually manage memory in C++, and list that as a negative point of the language (not to say ruediste is doing that). When in reality, you have the *option* of manually managing memory. An option that many other languages deny you, and an option which you are certainly not required to utilize. That's a positive, not a negative.

Comment: I disagree as well on the manually managing memory.. RAII exists for a reason.. So do containers like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.. Destructors are there for a reason..

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if my answers captures the point why the language designers did it the way they did, but given that I did a lot of C++ and Java programming, my answer would be: "*because there is no need to*".

In Java, I do not care about *where* the object is created.

The main difference between "object on the heap" and "object on the stack" in C++ is that in the latter case the object is automatically destroyed when it comes out of scope. In Java, this is the case even though the object was created on the heap, because Java has a garbage collector and checks if the reference "became out of scope" (in the sense that no part of the program is holding a reference to the object).

So in Java, objects are created on the heap, but from that "C++" perspective they behave as if there were created on a stack.

PS: An maybe one other aspect: In C++ stack size is/can be limited (much more than heap size), so creating a lot of object on the stack can be a problem.

Comment: Also, escape analysis often indeed *does* put Java objects on the stack. Not that anyone cares, though :)